# Microsoft Client Object Model web service

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I understand that using a managed client object model communicated via a web service to the Server-side Object Model.  But I can't find any documentation on whether this is a RESTful or SOAP service. Does anyone know of any documentation on this service architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Question.

Take this code for example:

```
 using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            clientContext.Credentials = getServiceAccountCredential();

            SP.List invoicesList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Approved Invoice Allocations");

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View> <Query> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Invoice_x0020_ID'/> <Value Type='Lookup'>" + invoice_id +
                                "</Value> </Eq> </Where> </Query> <RowLimit>1000</RowLimit> </View>";
            ListItemCollection collListItems = invoicesList.GetItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.Load(collListItems);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Looking at the request and response headers in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) tool when clientContext.ExecuteQuery or ExecuteQueryAsync is executed, below are some observations

1) A POST request is sent to SharePoint REST service webUrl/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery

2) Request sent is in XML format

3) Response is in JSON format

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388) MSDN article for more information